# no matching function for getline c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to input a number, and based on that number, the user would have to enter x amount of times.

For example

```
3 //how many the user wants
192 231 2 3
22192 2 1 23
2831 3 23 1
```

I tried doing this, but it keeps saying no matching function for `getline`

```
int* x = NULL;
int numbers;
cin >> numbers;
x = new int[numbers]

for (int i=0;i<numbers;i++)
{
    std::getline(std::cin, numbers)
    x[i] = numbers
}
```

Comment: Is there some spectacularly great reason you can't use `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: So, do you want to read in 3 (`numbers`) of lines of integers, 3 integers, or always `numbers` of lines of 4 integers? Also: You would be overwriting the loop bound every time, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not want to use `std::getline` as it doesn't look like you want a string of numbers, but rather numbers themselves.

What you want is to read number by number, so use the same thing you did to read in the `numbers`, but do not read it in `numbers` again. (Because you are using it in the loop.)

Anyway, an approximation of what you want is this:

```
int how_many;
std::vector<int> numbers;
std::cin >> how_many;
for (int i = 0; i < how_many; i++){
    int temp;
    std::cin >> temp;
    numbers.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: @Kara Then keep initializing `x` as you already do, read with `std::cin >> x[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter of the getline has type `std::string`

Comment: is there any way i can do it without being a string?

Comment: @Kara: You can look at the documentation and use any overload available. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @Kara You already figured out how to extract an `int` on line 3. But you shouldn't use `numbers` as your `int` because your `for` loop depends on it.